# Django view for facebook fan page tab

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-page

I am building a page tab for my site, it needs to custom by facebook's page id, that's why I created a view for this.

```
@csrf_exempt
def iframe_playlist(request):
code = request.REQUEST.get("signed_request", None)
code = 'none' if code == None else 'none'
return HttpResponse(code) #<<< I tried to output the request 
                #<<< and see if the request exists. but it always shows to none.
code = code.split('.', 2)
code = facebook.base64_url_encode(code)
code = json.loads(code)
uid = json['user_id']
site_user = get_object_or_404(FacebookProfile, uid=uid)
app = get_object_or_404(AppPage, user=site_user.user)
playlist = app.playlist
image = app.image if app.image else None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few different errors, most important one is in this line:

```
code = 'none' if code == None else 'none'
```

It basically says:

```
code = 'none' # Always!
```

No wonder that next lines always prints "none" ;) Moreover, you should use `if code is None` instead of `if code == None`, it's very important!

What you really need is to change these lines:

```
 code = request.REQUEST.get("signed_request", None)
 code = 'none' if code == None else 'none'
```

to:

```
code = request.REQUEST.get("signed_request", 'none')
```

And later on, when the code works, you won't even need to set string value "none" - it's just for debugging as I understand.

Additionally, the "signed_request" should be passed as POST by Facebook. And according to Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.REQUEST):

> It's strongly suggested that you use GET and POST instead of REQUEST,
>   because the former are more explicit.

If the first hint doesn't help, please check if your URL is correct, according to this: [Facebook iframe tab signed request always empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253830/facebook-iframe-tab-signed-request-always-empty)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback , will try it and come bqck to you