# signed_request is going away inside Facebook App

Tags: facebook, zend-framework, facebook-iframe

I just want to ask a question about Facebook "signed_request" thing.

I'm using Zend Framework for my app. 
The thing is; when user first authorizes my app OR enters the app from apps.facebook.com/my_app/ URL, I'm successfully retrieving signed_request.

Actually, I'm retrieving it from apps.facebook.com/my_app/index.php (Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253830/facebook-iframe-tab-signed-request-always-empty))

OK, app has been started, I received signed request, stored it in user session. However, when user clicks anywhere in my app, $facebook object is created again but this time, it has no signed_request.

According to [this topic on Codeplex](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/discussions/249564), I can expect that signed_request will come in this second request of user:

> Instead of using the cookie you should use the signed request value
>   that Facebook POSTS to your page on each request.

On the other hand, Facebook documentation says:

> A signed_request is passed to Apps on Facebook.com when they are
>   loaded into the Facebook environment

Now, does Facebook sends this request on each call or is there a technical problem on my app? Could it be an IFrame issue? When user click "categories", page is loading in same iframe and URL on address bar does not change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's basically a difference of definition on what "each request" means.  Facebook will POST signed_request to your page *only* when the containing iframe is first constructed, i.e. when the user goes directly to apps.facebook.com/your_app/somepage.php as their browser location.  If the user then follows a "normal" link on your page that results in only a reload of the iframe and not the entire page, no signed_request will be sent.  If it helps to think of it this way, signed_request is sent when the user first loads your app, but not on each subsequent request.  The reason there is some confusion about this is that many coders have taken a hackish shortcut by making all their links use `target=_top` and pointing them at apps.facebook.com/your_app/yourpage.php rather than www.yourdomain.com/yourpage.php.  Since that results in the entire page being re-constructed each time, it does indeed have the effect of sending signed_request with each page fetch.  But in normal (and recommended) operation, you'll need to count on signed_request only being sent once.

Comment: Nice and clear answer. I understand the issue now. Thank you for your informative comment :)