# Facebook PHP SDK 4 get id of fan page calling tab app

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have a facebook tab app that will be installed in multiple fan pages, but it must show different results. I tried with query strings, but from what I know, the tab link can´t have custom vars.

My idea is to get the id of the current fan page calling the tab app, and then pass it as a variable to define different results.

I tried with Facebook PHP SDK 4:

```
define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', 'src/Facebook/');
require 'autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookPageTabHelper;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('xxx', 'xxx');

$canvasHelper = new FacebookPageTabHelper();
var_dump( $canvasHelper );
```

but I get:

```
protected 'pageData' => null
protected 'signedRequest' => null
```

Any ideas?

SOLUTION:
after some hours of work and returning to FB SDK 3, I found this: [Facebook iframe tab signed request always empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253830/facebook-iframe-tab-signed-request-always-empty)
"After changing my "Tab URL" to 'tab/index.php", the signed request started to show up in the app tab!"
It works, even with SDK 4!

Comment: `$canvasHelper->getPageId()`

Comment: yes, i have that two lines below of "var_dump".. and it gives me null..
I think it has something to do with the pageData being null

Comment: You will only get that when it is rendered in the iframe on the first POST request. After that you need to remember it yourself